# Everything in my column time are the same whenever I try to update the time using SQLite Database in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sqlite

How do I fix the problem of the time column being the same whenever I try to update it using the SQLite Database, I'm only using basic SQLite Database knowledge, whenever I put null in the whereClause all of my rows are the same whenever I try to update the data in a singular row? What should I try to fix in this code so that the time column wouldn't be the same whenever I try to update it?

```
package com.radixappointment.radix;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import static com.radixappointment.radix.DatabaseReport.ID;

public class DatabaseInfo extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

/*Information Database*/
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "information.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "information_table";
public static final String ADMIN_NAME = "admin_table";
public static final String REPORT_NAME = "report_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "COMPANY_NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "CLIENT_NAME";
public static final String COL_4 = "CONTACT";
public static final String COL_5 = "TIME";
public static final String COL_6 = "STATUS";
public static final String COL_REPORT = "REPORT";


public DatabaseInfo(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, COMPANY_NAME TEXT, CLIENT_NAME TEXT, CONTACT TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + ADMIN_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, COMPANY_NAME TEXT, CLIENT_NAME TEXT, CONTACT TEXT, TIME TEXT, STATUS TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + REPORT_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, REPORT TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ADMIN_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + REPORT_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String Company, String Client, String Contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, Company);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, Client);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, Contact);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}

public boolean insertDataAdmin(String Company, String Client, String Contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase dbadmin = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, Company);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, Client);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, Contact);
    long adminresult = dbadmin.insert(ADMIN_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (adminresult == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}

public int updateTime (String Time) {
    SQLiteDatabase dbtime = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ID, Time);
    return dbtime.update(ADMIN_NAME, values, null, null);
}

public boolean insertReport(String Report) {
    SQLiteDatabase dbreport = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_REPORT, Report);
    long inputreport = dbreport.insert(REPORT_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (inputreport == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}

public Cursor getAllDataAdmin() {
    SQLiteDatabase dbadmin = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor admin = dbadmin.rawQuery("select * from " + ADMIN_NAME, null);
    return admin;
}

public Cursor getAllReportTable() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor report = db.rawQuery("select * from " + REPORT_NAME, null);
    return report;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be that ID does not resolve to the column name in `values.put(ID, Time);`.

I believe you should possibly be using :-

```
values.put(COL_5, Time);
```

However, as your code stands i.e. `return dbtime.update(ADMIN_NAME, values, null, null);` it will result in **all rows being updated with the new time**. As such you may need to provide a `WHERE` clause using the 3rd and 4th parameters, as per [SQLiteDatabase - update](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).

Assuming that you know the id of the row then the following may suit :-

```
public int updateTime (String Time, long Id) {
    SQLiteDatabase dbtime = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String whereclause = COL_1 + "=?";
    String whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(Id)};
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_5, Time);
    return dbtime.update(ADMIN_NAME, values, whereclause, whereargs);
}
```

Alternately you may prefer the following, which is effectively the same :-

```
public int updateTime (String Time, long Id) {
    SQLiteDatabase dbtime = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_5, Time);
    return dbtime.update(ADMIN_NAME, values, COL_1 + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(Id)});
}
```

Comment: so what should I put in my button? its getting error when I used get string
`submitBtnn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent submit = new Intent(FillupActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                myDb.updateTime(timeupdate.getText());

                startActivity(submit);
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: Instead of `timeupdate.getText()`, you should use `timeupdate.getText().toString()`.